# Long API Call - Async calls the answer?

Tags: c#, async-await

I am calling an external API which is slow.  Currently if I havent called the API to get some orders for a while the call can be broken up into pages (pagingation).

So therefore fetching orders could be making multiple calls rather than the 1 call.  Sometimes each call can be around 10 seconds per call so this could be about a minute in total which is far too long.

```
        GetOrdersCall getOrders = new GetOrdersCall();
        getOrders.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnSummary);
        getOrders.CreateTimeFrom = lastOrderDate;
        getOrders.CreateTimeTo = DateTime.Now;

        PaginationType paging = new PaginationType();
        paging.EntriesPerPage = 20;
        paging.PageNumber = 1;

        getOrders.Pagination = paging;

        getOrders.Execute();

        var response = getOrders.ApiResponse;
        OrderTypeCollection orders = new OrderTypeCollection();

        while (response != null && response.OrderArray.Count > 0)
        {
            eBayConverter.ConvertOrders(response.OrderArray, 1);

            if (response.HasMoreOrders)
            {
                getOrders.Pagination.PageNumber++;
                getOrders.Execute();

                response = getOrders.ApiResponse;
                orders.AddRange(response.OrderArray);
            }
        }
```

This is a summary of my code above... The getOrders.Execute() is when the api fires.

After the 1st "getOrders.Execute()" there is a Pagination result which tells me how many pages of data there are.  My thinking is that I should be able to start an asnychronous call for each page and to populate the OrderTypeCollection.  When all the calls are made and the collection is fully loaded then I will commit to the database.

I have never done Asynchronous calls via c# before and I can kind of follow Async await but I think my scenario falls out of the reading I have done so far?

Questions:

1. I think I can set it up to fire off the multiple calls asynchronously but I'm not sure how to check when all tasks have been completed i.e. ready to commit to db.
2. I've read somewhere that I want to avoid combining the API call and the db write to avoid locking in SQL server - Is this correct?

If someone can point me in the right direction - It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the ebay api ;) slow as

Comment: The problem isn't so much to do things async (that's not going to make it faster) but rather to make calls in parallel. As TheGeneral says, ebay doesn't have async support anyway. So, you could spin up x threads that each perform a synchonous call per page. Just dont go spawning 20 threads.  Spawn = CPU count.  Or you might want to take a look at _TPL DataFlow_.  Better long term investment.

Comment: @MickyD Yes sorry my terminology is probably incorrect.  Making these calls in parrallel is what I'm looking for.  I am investigating the answer from the TheGeneral

Comment: No worries.  I agree with TheGeneral's answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I can set it up to fire off the multiple calls asynchronously
>   but I'm not sure how to check when all tasks have been completed i.e.
>   ready to commit to db.

Yes you can break this up

The problem is *ebay* doesn't have an `async Task Execute` Method, so you are left with blocking threaded calls and no *IO optimised* async await pattern. If there were, you could take advantage of a *TPL Dataflow* pipeline which is `async` aware (and fun for the whole family to play), you could anyway, though i propose a vanilla *TPL* solution...

However, all is not lost, just fall back to `Parallel.For` and a `ConcurrentBag<OrderType>`

**Example**

```
var concurrentBag = new ConcurrentBag<OrderType>();


// make first call
// add results to concurrentBag
// pass the pageCount to the for
int pagesize = ...;

Parallel.For(1, pagesize,
   page =>
      {
         // Set up
         // add page
         // make Call 

         foreach(var order in getOrders.ApiResponse)
            concurrentBag.Add(order);
      });

// all orders have been downloaded
// save to db
```

**Note** : There are `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` which you configure, maybe set it to 50, though it wont really matter how much you give it, the *Task Scheduler* is not going to aggressively give you threads, maybe 10 or so initially and grow slowly.

The other way you can do this, is create your own *Task Scheduler*, or just spin up your own Threads with the old fashioned `Thread` Class

---

> I've read somewhere that I want to avoid combining the API call and
>   the db write to avoid locking in SQL server - Is this correct?

- If you mean locking as in slow DB insert, use Sql Bulk Insert and update tools.
- If you mean locking as in the the DB deadlock error message, then this is an entirely different thing, and worthy of its own question

---

**Additional Resources**

[For(Int32, Int32, ParallelOptions, Action)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_For_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelOptions_System_Action_System_Int32__)

> Executes a for (For in Visual Basic) loop in which iterations may run
>   in parallel and loop options can be configured.

[ParallelOptions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Stores options that configure the operation of methods on the Parallel
>   class.
>
> **MaxDegreeOfParallelism**
>
> Gets or sets the maximum number of concurrent tasks enabled by this
>   ParallelOptions instance.

[ConcurrentBag Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Represents a thread-safe, unordered collection of objects.

Comment: Im investigating your response now... there are a number of things to look at here but I'm sure you've given me what I need.  To respond to the db question.  Yes I think it is deadlocks that I need to be worried about?  So you agree that I shouldn't be writing to the DB within the task itself - to avoid deadlocks?

Comment: @GlenHong with `parallel.For` it waits for all threads to finish, ergo, you only need the one single threaded db operation after the fact. There are however many reasons for a DB deadlock and it is entirely dependent on your database, the schema and your sql

Comment: thank you works perfectly.  Any hints on how to handle if one of these threads has an error i.e timeout ?

Comment: @GlenHong you could you add a retry mech in the code block for the page. or you could catch and add another concurrentbag to tell you afterwards which page failed and why. maybe a mixture of both

Comment: Thanks...I found this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-parallel-loops which helps.  I think realistically the only thing that could happen here is maybe a timeout or loss of connection.  For now I'll just do a catch all and report back to user to try again.  Further on I will implement as you suggest a retry...

Comment: @GlenHong sounds like a plan, and nice link

Comment: I might just add that I had to define the GetOrdersCall within the Parallel.For otherwise I think it was getting confused and the Concurrent bag count wasnt all the orders.  Defining the variables within the loop solved this problem

Comment: Quick question though - I have 3 stores and I was thinking of running a nested Parallel.for (one for each store) and then nested (one for each page of results) - is this do-able?  I'll ask a new question if you want?

Comment: @GlenHong yeah you can nest safely, however the system will only give you so many threads in nay case, maybe 10 to start. If you really want higher through put, you could spin up the `Thread` Class and manage them

Answer (score 0):

Yes `ConcurrentBag<T>` Class can be used to server the purpose of one of your questions which was: "I think I can set it up to fire off the multiple calls asynchronously but I'm not sure how to check when all tasks have been completed i.e. ready to commit to db."

This generic class can be used to Run your every task and wait all your tasks to be completed to do further processing. It is thread safe and useful for parallel processing.

Comment: If i am not mistaken this is the ebay api, and there is no async methods. also this doesn't solve the problem of getting orders asynchronously to save time

Comment: Thank you for your information, I have not worked on ebay api yet. But will do research on this.